# Parsing string separated by commas in C - Arduino

Tags: c, arduino, lcd

I would like to be able to parse a string separated by commas on my Arduino.
I send to my device text string like

```
Somebody,Natalia Le Rose,,
```

which is generated by C#

```
        //creating string that will be send to arduino
    string message = SongTitleNotification + "," + SongArtistNotification + "," + FacebookNotification + "," + GmailNotification;

    //sending message

    SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600);
    port.Open();
    port.Write(message);
    port.Close();
```

and it receives my sketch

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(20, 4);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{

 while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    lcd.clear();
    delay(100);
    // look for the next valid integer in the incoming serial stream:
    char title = Serial.parseInt();
    // do it again:
    char artist = Serial.parseInt();
    // do it again:
    char fb = Serial.parseInt();
    char gmail = Serial.parseInt();

    lcd.print(title);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(artist);
    lcd.setCursor(0,2);
    lcd.print(fb);
    lcd.setCursor(0,3);
    lcd.print(gmail);

    }
    delay(3500);
  }
```

but the lcd does not show the variables.
What should I do? :)

Comment: First check that you are receiving anything at all.

Comment: yes, I am. I used to try lcd.print(Serial.read); and it worked correctly

Comment: And the string you are getting is actually numbers separated by comas?

Comment: not numbers but words. ex. Somebody,Natalia Le Rose,,

Comment: So how do you expect it to be parsed as `int`s?

Comment: Seems like you want to use readStringUntil() with the comma as a delimeter.

Comment: Why it is tagged `C`? it does not look like `C`, at all.

Comment: @SouravGhosh It's Arduino - a crazy mix of C and C++ and some weird processing..

Comment: There's also the problem that `title`, `artist`, `fb`, and `gmail` are declared as *single* character values, not strings.  Not an Arduino programmer, but I *think* you're looking for something like `String title;...title=Serial.readStringUntil(',');`, where `String` is a type supplied by the Arduino development environment.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197097/how-read-string-from-serial).

Answer (score 0):

For parsing strings using a delimeter, consider using strtok.  You should create a buffer that your Serial reads into, then parse that

```
char buffer[50];
uint8_t bufferReadIndex = 0;
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    buffer[bufferReadIndex++] = Serial.read();
}
char* stringPtr;
stringPtr = strtok(&buffer, ",");
while (stringPtr != NULL)
{
    Serial.println(stringPtr);
    stringPtr = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
```