# Arduino convert ascii characters to string

Tags: string, arduino, ascii

I'm using this sensor with an arduino board.

On page 2, it describes the serial output from pin 5.

http://www.maxbotix.com/documents/HRXL-MaxSonar-WR_Datasheet.pdf

> The output is an ASCII capital "R", followed by four ASCII character
>   digits representing the range in millimeters,followed by a carriage
>   return (ASCII 13). The serial data format is 9600 baud, 8 data bits, no parity,
>   with one stop bit (9600-8-N-1).

This is my arduino code (which isn't correct). It only outputs the '82' which is the capital R.

```
void setup()
{  
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{  
 int data = Serial.read();
 Serial.println(data);
 delay (1000);
}
```

How do I get a distance reading to a string?

Many thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197097/how-read-string-from-serial

Comment: Sorry but.. Where did you attach the sensor? Cause I see you are using the same serial port for both reading and writing...this COULD work if you just plug in the TX cable of the sensor in the RX cable of the arduino, but then you can't read from the PC. I suggest you to use the software serial library fot the sensor, then just use the example [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample) (just set the correct baud rates)

Answer (score 2):

Do you tried the `readBytesUntil` method ?

You should use it [like that](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StreamReadBytesUntil) :

```
byte DataToRead [6];
Serial.readBytesUntil(char(13), DataToRead, 6);
```

Your data is contained into `DataToRead` (your 'R' in `DataToRead[0]` etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's great. So would this print out the actual distance.   `void setup()
{  
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{  
 byte DataToRead [6];
Serial.readBytesUntil(char(13), DataToRead, 6);
int data = DataToRead [1:4];
Serial.println(data);
delay (1000);
}`

Comment: You can try to put 4 bytes into an integer but I'm not sure is it works. Otherwise you can try somthing like this:
`union { // declared above setup{}
  byte b[4];
  int i;
} tmp;`
 And in your loop :
`tmp.b[0]=DataToRead[1];
      tmp.b[1]=DataToRead[2];
      tmp.b[2]=DataToRead[3];
      tmp.b[3]=DataToRead[4];
data = tmp.i;`

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, the question was:
How do you convert a byte (ascii) representation of a character into a readable alpha-numeric character like "a" versus 97?

The actual quesion: Arduino convert ascii characters to string.
Why do ppl post responses that don't answer the question?

Not exact answer but casting with (char) will get you on the way there.

```
char inByte  = 0;
inByte = (char)Serial.read();  // ascii 97 received
Serial.println((char)inByte); // => prints an 'a' without the quotes
```