# C# Serial Communications issues with Arduino

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, .net-4.5, baud-rate

I have been struggling with commincations speeds with some code.

So i want to increase the baud rate for both the code & Arduino. But if i leave the 9600 baud rate, the data stops sending & reciving properly.
So i set up a simple test program.

Arduino Code:

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.setTimeout(10);
}

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available())
    {
        String Data = Serial.readStringUntil('#');
        if (Data == "Test")
        {
            Serial.println("Recived");
        }
    }
    delay(1);
}
```

c# Code:

```
SerialPort Port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600);
Port.Open();
if (Port.IsOpen)
{
     Port.Write("Test#");
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
     String Read = Port.ReadExisting();
     Port.Close();
}
```

So running that String Read comes back with "Recived\r\n".
Change the baud rate to 19200 and it comes back with "".

Any ideas why this is occuring?

Edit: If I use the Arduino IDE's Serial Monitor Program, this works just fine regardless of baudrate used. Its as soon as i use c# that it that this issue occurs. Which rules out hardware issues I believe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197097/how-to-read-a-string-value-with-a-delimeter-on-arduino

Comment: You have to set the Handshake property.  If you don't then you'll get the handshake mode that whatever program you used last used for that port.  Or the system default if you did not use such a program or if the program restores it when it closes the port.  Which tends to be very troublesome for Arduino since it doesn't implement the handshake signals.  You'll have to set it to Handshake.None explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou for you inputs.

Think i have found a solution, although not to clear about why.

I think it was due to the `Serial.Avalible()` Command. Appears i needed to send though some data first to make it register the port is open.

So modifying my C# code to this: Works

```
SerialPort Port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600);
Port.Open();
if (Port.IsOpen)
{
     Port.Write("#");
     Port.Write("Test#");
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
     String Read = Port.ReadExisting();
     Port.Close();
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a character at a time from the PC and use Serial.read() to read a character into a buffer in the arduino. Sometimes sending the whole text from PC at high baud rate is too much for the arduino to handle.